# How to search recursively for a string in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to search recursively for files containing a string. I want to search:

1. Files in and under the directory I'm standing in currently
2. A specific directory.

I want to see only results. I don't want to see "permission denied" messages or other things. Only the file locations that contain the string I search for.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -lr searchstring * /path/to/dir 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Using `.` instead of `*` will include hidden files in the current directory as well, not just in the subdirectories.

Comment: Were using `grep -r | sed s/:.*//`.