# How to find the line containing a string in a file?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search for a string in a line and return line and line numbers in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/436402/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-a-line-and-return-line-and-line-numbers-in-linux)

I have a file `myfile`. I will search for a string in this file.

I want to see the line number, and the line that contains the string in the output.
The string contains white spaces, so the search will be like this:

```
>>>mysearch myfile "my string"
>>>line 324: this line contains my string
```

Could you please help?

Best Regards

Comment: Did you forget the answer to your [other similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/436402/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-a-line-and-return-line-and-line-numbers-in-linux) or [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/427541/how-to-search-recursively-for-a-string-in-linux)? `grep` is for searching, `man grep` is for learning more about searching.